# How to document Cargo features?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rustdoc

I'm using [Cargo features](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html) for conditional compilation of some things in a library.

As I'm documenting the library, I noticed that the Cargo features appear nowhere in the generated documentation. When I generated the docs with `cargo doc --all-features`, I expected to see some kind of label telling the user that struct X is available only with feature Y is enabled.

Writing this information on each item manually seems to be very error-prone, so is there a way to generate such a thing automatically?